# How to select JSON grammar from atom command script?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using Atom with my init.js below, the objective are :

1. select all
2. Prettify json
3. Change grammar to json

I'm having difficulties with step #3, below is my script :

```js
atom.commands.add("atom-workspace", {
  "custom:prettify-json": function() {
    var view;
    view = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor());
    atom.commands.dispatch(view, "core:select-all");
    atom.commands.dispatch(view, "pretty-json:prettify");
    atom.commands.dispatch(view, "grammar-selector:show");

    return true;
  }
});
```

So far I only found that grammar-sellector only has show function, is there any way to choose "source.json" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the private method `setGrammar()` that has been around since forever. It should serve the task, unless the developers decide to remove/replace it in future versions.

```js
atom.commands.add("atom-workspace", {
  "custom:prettify-json": function() {
    const editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor();
    const view = atom.views.getView(editor);

    atom.commands.dispatch(view, "core:select-all");
    atom.commands.dispatch(view, "pretty-json:prettify");

    editor.setGrammar(atom.grammars.grammarForScopeName('source.json'));

    return true;
  }
});
```